# Renaming columns in a list with lapply and gsub

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, gsub

Suppose I want to rename columns by removing special characters in the following list of data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame("x.1" = runif(3), "y.1" = runif(3))
df2 <- data.frame("x.2" = runif(3), "y.2" = runif(3))
df.list <- list(df1, df2)
```

I've tried the following code..

```
 dplyr::df.list <- lapply(df.list, function(y) gsub("\\.", "", colnames(y)))
```

How can I `lapply()` with `gsub()` to remove the special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.list <- lapply(df.list, function(y) {colnames(y) <- gsub("\\.", "", colnames(y)); y})
df.list
```